# Excel addin in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, add-in

I am trying to create addin for excel that has a dropdown and a button.

I was successfully able to add button, but for some reason, I was not able to add dropdown to it.

Here is the code for button, this is calld in ThisAddIn_startup:

```
 try
            {
                _commandBar = Application.CommandBars["commandBar"];
                _commandBar.Delete();


            }
            catch (ArgumentException e)
            {
            }

            // Add a commandbar named Test.

            _commandBar = Application.CommandBars.Add("button1", Office.MsoBarPosition.msoBarRight, missing, true);

            // Add a button to the command bar and an event handler.
            _firstButton = (Office.CommandBarButton)_commandBar.Controls.Add(
                Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing, missing, missing, missing);

            _firstButton.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
                      _firstButton.Click += new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(firstButton_ButtonClick);

            _commandBar.Visible = true;
```

After doing some more research on google, I thought it was simpler to add ribbon designer and use that for adding more controls to the addin. But I am not able to view that ribbon on excel when I run the project.

I am totally lost what is the better solution for this.

Any help/link would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could use the same solution with Excel addin, by changing the line,

```
  _commandBar = Application.CommandBars.Add("button1", Office.MsoBarPosition.msoBarRight, missing, true);
```

to

```
_commandBar = Application.CommandBars.Add("button1", missing, missing, true);
```

By removing the position, I could add as many controls on the addin, as I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Excel 2007 you can activate the developer ribbon by going to the main excel menu (big button on the top left), then in the bottom right of that dialog there is an excel options button.  From there, go to popular and select Show Developer tab in the Ribbon.

Comment: it doesn't show the developer ribbon tab, or the option wasn't there?

Comment: what version of excel are you running?

Comment: 2007. Actually I want to know which way is better. I have the version of Addin working with just button.  I am struggling to add other components to it. Its just whatever is working.. ribbon or Addin..